# Numerical evaluation of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have to evaluate numerically $f(z)$ via the Cauchy representation (so via a complex integral), in other words, I have to calculare $f(z)$ performing a complex integral:

$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_\Gamma \dfrac{f(t)}{t-z}dt$

I have found some matlab algoritms that performs this calculations via a mean, I would like to understand where does this procedure derive from.

Could someone explain me this derivation or give me any reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(t)$ is a holomorfic function and $\Gamma$ represents a closed integration path that contains $z$, then you can use Cauchy's integral formula

$\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma dt\,\frac{f(t)}{t-z}$.

**EDIT:**

You have changed the question. To find a derivation, wikipedia gives you a proof for a small circular circuit. You can use Cauchy's integral theorem to understand that any circuit that encloses $z$ must yield the same result.

Comment: Yes I know, I edited the question because it was unclear. I need to calculare the integral numerically in order to determine $f(z)$

Comment: It's a path integral, where $dt$ represents a "length" differential, if you want. I would parameterize $t = e^{i\theta}$ and numerically integrate over $\theta$.

Comment: How would one evaluate the integral $ \oint_{C}\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}$ via Complex methods  ?